# How to check if duplicate values occur in a certain range and also pick one corresponding value out of them

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

```
Loc        V2
0.115   -68.6976
2.1641  0.5862
2.81    22.4652
2.81    58.2354
4.2132  97.2793
0.1875  -28.3827
1.3335  -1.23
2.4795  25.9228
```

[image]

In the above list you can see that 2.81 occurs twice, but its corresponding value in next column is different. I want to identify and pick the higher value (i.e 58.2354) out of the two. I have to pick this value based on the first column values, but since there are two identical values here I am not getting the result Ii desire. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Pivot Table will give you what you ask for.

Comment: You mean to say in Column E 2.81 has two corresponding values in Column G and you want to pick the highest among both ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check the Screen Shot. My solution has found the highest among two, 2.81 entries.**

[image]

I've used the below written Formula,

```
{=INDEX($G$3:$G$10, LARGE(IF(COUNTIF($E$3:$E$10, $E$3:$E$10)>1, ROW($E$3:$E$10)-MIN(ROW($E$3:$E$10))+1, ""), ROW(A1)))}
```

**NB:**

1.Remember it's an Array Formula so finish it with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

2. I've highlighted 2.81 and corresponding Values in Red along with the 58.2354 in Green, just to DRAW ATTENTION only.

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: Hi Rajesh, Thank you very much for your help. With slight modification to your formula  i was able to fix my problem

Comment: Nice to hear from you,, keep asking.